# InfluxDB: Query to select data from two time ranges at the same time

Tags: where-clause, logical-operators, influxdb, multiple-conditions

I am using InfluxDB for tick data from Tokyo Stock Exchange, where trading happens between 09:30 and 11:30 (AM session) and then from 12:30 to 15:00 (PM session), with a one hour lunch break from 11:30 to 12:30. I am interested in analyzing data from the both sessions, but not from the lunch break.

The following query works and gives me results

```
SELECT COUNT(<fieldname>) FROM <measurementname> where
(time >= '2017-11-01 09:00:00' and time < '2017-11-01 11:30:00') and
<other_conditions>
```

The following query also works and gives me results

```
SELECT COUNT(<fieldname>) FROM <measurementname> where 
(time >= '2017-11-01 12:30:00' and time < '2017-11-01 15:00:00') 
and <other_conditions>
```

But if I try the following, it does not work: I get an empty result with a warning (no series returned)

```
SELECT COUNT(<fieldname>) FROM <measurementname> where 
((time >= '2017-11-01 09:00:00' and time < '2017-11-01 11:30:00') or (time >= '2017-11-01 12:30:00' and time < '2017-11-01 15:00:00')) 
and <other_conditions>
```

How can I combine the two time conditions for AM and PM session into one query?

Comment: Ever work this out?

Answer (score 0):

For recent InfluxDB versions 2.X, it now uses Flux for querying and there is a solution for such problems here:
https://community.influxdata.com/t/query-specific-time-range-and-day/14503